# How do I go through a directory and test each file on their character length?

Tags: shell

We just started shell programming in class and we have to write a program which should list all names in the current directory from length 3 til 5.
I am trying to get the code together but it is somehow hard. This is as far as I've come but it won't work.

```
for f in ls
do
if [ $f | wc -m -gt 3 -a $f |wc -m -lt 6 ]
then
echo $f
fi
done
```

I would be thankful for every helpful response !

Comment: Do you mean the names should be between 3 and 5 characters or the size of the file should be between 3 and 5 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need `for f in *`; it’s possible to use `$(ls)`, but that won’t handle spaces right.
2. You need to use `$()` to actually run the commands in your tests:

   ```
   $(echo "$f" | wc -m) -gt 3
   ```

   Note the `echo`; you don’t want to run `$f` as a command!
3. Avoid using `test`’s logical operators like `-a`; it can’t do real expression parsing, so they aren’t fully reliable.
4. Just use `${#f}` instead of calling `wc`.

Answer (score 1):

`(shopt -s nullglob; echo ??? ???? ?????)`

`nullglob` option causes all non-matched wildcards to be turned to empty strings. For example if you only have a file named "test" in the directory, you'd get '??? test ?????' without `nullglob`.

I've added a subshell so that nullglob isn't set for the whole terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-liner using [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)):

```
find . -type f -iname "???" -o -iname "?????"
```

The `?`  is a [file globbing wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) that matches any single character, so to search for files of only 3 characters, `???` could be used.

Regarding the `-o` From the find man page:

> The operator -or was implemented as -o, and the operator -and was implemented as -a

So this example will return only files with a character length of 3 or 5

Another variant to print all files with a name between 3 and 5 characters could be using a regular expression, something like this:

```
find . -type f -exec basename '{}' + | egrep '^.{3,5}$'
```

In this case, `find` will search for all files within the current directory `.` and then call `basename` to remove leading slashes, `egrep` or `grep -E` then is used to only print files of length between 3 and 5 characters by using the regular expression `^.{3,5}$`